# Create variable validation in terraform that takes into account two fields of a map(object) type

Tags: terraform

I have the following `map(object)` variable in terraform.

```
variable "sm_secrets" {
  type = map(object({
    name                    = string,
    description             = string,
    recovery_window_in_days = optional(number),
    create_sms_policy       = optional(bool),
    access_pattern          = optional(string)
  }))
```

How can I provide a validation that checks that if `create_sms_policy` is set to true, the `access_pattern` is not null neither `""`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can apply some mathematical logic and take advantage of short circuit evaluation to achieve this:

```
validation {
  condition     = alltrue([for key, attrs in var.sm_secrets : (attrs.create_sms_policy == null || attrs.create_sms_policy == false) || (attrs.access_pattern != null && length(attrs.access_pattern) > 0)])
  error_message = "access_pattern must be specified and not empty if create_sms_policy is true"
}
```

Walking through the logic here:

- If `create_sms_policy` is `null` then we do not need to validate `access_pattern` and immediately stop.
- Else if `create_sms_policy` is `false` then we again we do not need to validate `access_pattern` and immediately stop.
- Otherwise `create_sms_policy` is `true` as this is the set subtraction of `null` and `false` from all possibilities. Therefore we need to validate `access_pattern` and, sure enough, the first logical evaluates to `false` and we proceed to evaluate the second logical for `access_pattern`.
- We now validate that `access_pattern` is both not `null` nor is it empty.

Note also that it is important here to evaluate the `null` equality or inequality first and short circuit accordingly as otherwise Terraform will error attempting to access a nonexistent value.

As for the outer expressions:

- We use a `for` expression to iterate through all of the key value pairs in the `map`.
- We use a `list` constructor to collect all of the returned booleans from the expression.
- We use the `alltrue` function to verify that each key-value pair in the variable input satisfies the validation condition because it returns `true` if every `list(bool)` element is `true`.

Comment: Aaah, that's what I was missing, I thought it had to be `var.sm_secrets.create_sms_policy`. Great.

Comment: @MarkoE That is indeed the correct syntax for accessing, and I made a mistake; corrected in answer.

Comment: Ha, I thought there was something I was missing, it would be rather convenient to be able to access elements of a map as a variable local to the declared variable. :)

Comment: @MarkoE Right I made another mistake and needed to use the standard `alltrue` combined with the `list` constructor and `for` expression to validate every key value pair in the `map`. Fixed again.

Comment: I think `len` should be changed to `length` as well

Comment: @pkaramol yes too much Go and Rust coding recently; another update fix.

Comment: @MattSchuchard to avoid polluting the discussion, I opened another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75022058/error-in-validation-of-2-fields-in-mapobject-type-variable-in-terraform) with the issue you proposed